# Spring boot swagger ApiModel for thirdparty classes

Tags: java, api, spring-boot, swagger

There are latest spring boot, swagger and maven. There is simple REST controller:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Simple controller")
@GetMapping("/resource/{id}")
public Money findMoney(@PathVariable String id) {
    return moneyService.findMoneyById(id);
}
```

Money is external class that I cannot change. But I do not want to display all its fields. And also I want to add some details on required fields. I would like to have something like:

```
@ApiModel(description = "Money model")
public class Money {
    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Just ignore it, hidden = true)
    private String notImportantProperty;
    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Currency")
    private String currency;
etc...

}
```

Comment: Are you using springfox?

Comment: yes <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: If you can't change the model class (and can't add annotations), it seems like you'll have to try using a JSON spec instead of code annotations. Maybe [this](https://dzone.com/articles/overcoming-swagger-annotation-overload-by-switchin) helps.